# Creating button in td using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, edit

I am trying to create a button in a table every time that the add button is clicked. I am having trouble with the button being displayed in the td. Im sure that it has to do with my JS. Any help would be appreciated.
HTML:

```
                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="myCreateFunction()">
      Add new
    </button>
                            <table class="table table-striped" border="4" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" id="usertable">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Supervisor</th>
                                    <th>Holiday</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>

                                </tr>
                                <?php while ($rowemployeelist = mysql_fetch_array($employeelistresult)) { ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $rowemployeelist["first_name"] ?>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $rowemployeelist ["last_name"] ?>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $rowemployeelist ["title"]?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $rowemployeelist ["supervisor"]?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $rowemployeelist ["holiday"]?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><button class="editbtn">Edit</button></td>

                                    <td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </table>
```

JS:

```
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("usertable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);

    cell1.innerHTML = "";
    cell2.innerHTML = "";
    cell3.innerHTML = "";
    cell4.innerHTML = "";
    var button = document.createElement("button")
    button. innerHTML = "Do Something";
    var td = document. getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    td.appendChild(button);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table, which td do you want the button to be added into? Is it the 5th cell in the new row?

I believe you want to find the correct td by using `row.findElementsByClassName` instead of `document.findElementsByClassName`

Alternatively, you could simply append the button directly to one of the cells you just created using `cell5.appendChild(button)`

Comment: Correct, I want it to be added to the 5th cell

Comment: @LucasBrawdy See my edit, you can directly append the child to the 5th cell.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact requirement. But Where are you creating the button? In javascript, you should have `var button = document.createElement("button")` to create a button. Add this line before using `button.innerHTML`
Changed code -

```
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("usertable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);

    cell1.innerHTML = "";
    cell2.innerHTML = "";
    cell3.innerHTML = "";
    cell4.innerHTML = "";
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Do Something";
    var td = document. getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    td.appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: Whenver I try this, i get a blank row still with no button added into the cell

Comment: Please have a look at this working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/pzw79pf1/. Please correct me if this is not your requirement.